# get id from json recycleview retrofit2

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to get the id from the json from the API so if I click on a user it will get the id from json on the clicked user, how do I do that?

My app looks like this:

[image: app]

The JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Tester 1",
    "online": "0",
    "profileimg": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/af/9c/6a/af9c6a69e7556ffcae42de85735f5a97.jpg",
    "distancekm": 16286,
    "distancem": 10119
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Tester 2",
    "online": "0",
    "profileimg": "http://assets1.ignimgs.com/2014/10/07/ironmanjpg-affbef_1280w.jpg",
    "distancekm": 6216,
    "distancem": 3863
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Tester 3",
    "online": "0",
    "profileimg": "",
    "distancekm": 1,
    "distancem": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Tester 4",
    "online": "0",
    "profileimg": "",
    "distancekm": 1,
    "distancem": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Tester 5",
    "online": "0",
    "profileimg": "",
    "distancekm": 1,
    "distancem": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Tester 6",
    "online": "0",
    "profileimg": "",
    "distancekm": 1,
    "distancem": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "Tester 7",
    "online": "0",
    "profileimg": "",
    "distancekm": 1,
    "distancem": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "name": "Tester 8",
    "online": "0",
    "profileimg": "",
    "distancekm": 1,
    "distancem": 1
  }
]
```

NearbyUsersAdapter:

```
public class NearbyUsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NearbyUsersAdapter.NearbyUsersViewHolder> {

private List<NearbyUsers> nearbyusers;
private int rowLayout;
private Context context;
private SQLiteHandler db;

public static class NearbyUsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout NearbyUserLayout;
    ImageView NearbyUserImage;
    TextView NearbyUserUserName;
    TextView NearbyUserDistance;
    ImageView NearbyUserOnline;

    public NearbyUsersViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        NearbyUserLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.nearbyusers_layout);
        NearbyUserImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        NearbyUserUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        NearbyUserDistance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        NearbyUserOnline = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.isonline);
    }
}

public NearbyUsersAdapter(List<NearbyUsers> nearbyusers, int rowLayout, Context context) {
    this.nearbyusers = nearbyusers;
    this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public NearbyUsersAdapter.NearbyUsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                        int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
    return new NearbyUsersViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NearbyUsersViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    db = new SQLiteHandler(context);

    Integer uid = nearbyusers.get(position).getId();
    String thumbimage = nearbyusers.get(position).getProfileimg();
    Integer useronline = nearbyusers.get(position).getOnline();

    if (thumbimage.isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_no_user)
                .resize(80, 80)
                .into(holder.NearbyUserImage);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(context).load(thumbimage)
                .resize(80, 80)
                .into(holder.NearbyUserImage);
    }

    holder.NearbyUserUserName.setText(nearbyusers.get(position).getName());

    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    String measure = user.get("unit_of_measure");

    if (measure.equals("Metric")) {
        holder.NearbyUserDistance.setText(String.valueOf(nearbyusers.get(position).getDistancekm()) + " Km");
    }
    if (measure.equals("US Standard")) {
        holder.NearbyUserDistance.setText(String.valueOf(nearbyusers.get(position).getDistancekm()) + " Mi");
    }

    if (useronline.equals(1)) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.onlineindicator)
                .into(holder.NearbyUserOnline);
    }
    if (useronline.equals(0)) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.offlineindicator)
                .into(holder.NearbyUserOnline);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return nearbyusers.size();
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private NearbyUsersAdapter.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final NearbyUsersAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

My NearByUsersFragment:

```
public class NearByUsersFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean mSearchCheck;
    private static final String TEXT_FRAGMENT = "TEXT_FRAGMENT";
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    private AdView mAdView;

    public static NearByUsersFragment newInstance(String text){
        NearByUsersFragment mFragment = new NearByUsersFragment();
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putString(TEXT_FRAGMENT, text);
        mFragment.setArguments(mBundle);
        return mFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearbyusers, container, false);

        mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nearbyusers_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        db = new SQLiteHandler(getContext());

        // Fetching user details from SQLite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        final String apiKey = user.get("apiKey");

        final ApiInterface apiService =
                RestClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loadingusers));
        pDialog.show();

        Call<List<NearbyUsers>> call = apiService.NearbyUsers(apiKey);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<NearbyUsers>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<NearbyUsers>> call, Response<List<NearbyUsers>> response) {

                if (response.code() == 401) {
                    pDialog.hide();
                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    List<NearbyUsers> nearbysers = response.body();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new NearbyUsersAdapter(nearbysers, R.layout.list_item_nearbyusers, getContext()));
                }
                pDialog.hide();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<NearbyUsers>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("NearbyUserFragment", t.toString());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new NearbyUsersAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getContext(), recyclerView, new NearbyUsersAdapter.ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("position", position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ID:" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nearbyuserswipeRefreshLayout);

        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loadingusers));
                pDialog.show();

                Call<List<NearbyUsers>> call = apiService.NearbyUsers(apiKey);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<NearbyUsers>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<NearbyUsers>> call, Response<List<NearbyUsers>> response) {

                        if (response.code() == 401) {
                            pDialog.hide();
                        } else {
                            List<NearbyUsers> nearbysers = response.body();
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(new NearbyUsersAdapter(nearbysers, R.layout.list_item_nearbyusers, getContext()));
                        }
                        pDialog.hide();
                        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<NearbyUsers>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("NearbyUserFragment", t.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();
                        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        //Select search item
        final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        menuItem.setVisible(true);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint(this.getString(R.string.search));

        ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text))
                .setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nliveo_white));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(onQuerySearchView);

        mSearchCheck = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_search:
            mSearchCheck = true;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.search, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }   

   private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener onQuerySearchView = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
           if (mSearchCheck){
               // implement your search here
           }
           return false;
       }
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the items mapped to the Java object named NearbyUsers.

Put the getter for object you already have `nearbyusers` in the adapter. Like so:

```
public List<NearbyUsers> getNearbyUsers(){
       return nearbyUsers;
}
```

In the `OnClick` method from the `OnItemTouchListener` you can use then:

```
 ((NearbyUsersAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).getNearbyUsers().get(position).getId()
```